# Finding a function where its finite series of N elements sums X

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello :) First post and math newbie here!

I have a financial task where resources are distributed into N buckets, let's say 25, following a linear decreasing function. I want to alter this function so I can redistribute the resources increasing the value at the first buckets.

I could just alter the slope of the line, but I can only do it so much where I won't have negative numbers at the end. So I have to change the shape of the function and make it non-linear.

I have tried a function of the shape $a - b(log(x))$ where $a$ is my arbitrary starting point and $b$ is a constant I have calculated with this formula using theorems of sum of finite series:

$\sum_{i=1}^n a -b(log(i)) = na -b (log(n!)) = r$

Where r is the amount of resources I have to distribute.

It's already much better, but my problem is that I can still only push my arbitrary starting point $a$ so high until I have the same issue I was having with the linear function and then the tail is too low. Any ideas how I could go about this? (Apart from increasing the amount of resources or decreasing the number of buckets)

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: exponential function? Of the form ($Ae^{-bx}+c$)?

Comment: Thanks!! I will try that, but then there is more than one constant to find? How would you suggest I tackled that?

Comment: I would keep $c=0$ unless you really need to change it. You can play with $A$ and $b$ to your liking.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Keeping c at 0 didn't work for me, it was performing worse than my previous attempt with log. The tail was still too small. So I actually defined c to what was minimally accepted and manually fiddled with b to automatically calculate A based on sum function. That worked like a charm! Thanks